# How to get data from fieldset in Sencha Touch 2?

Tags: touch, extjs

I hava a fieldset in Sencha Touch 2 as follows:

```
{
                    id:'contactForm',
                    xtype: 'fieldset',
                    title: 'Information',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            label: 'First Name',
                            placeHolder: 'Your First Name',
                            name:'firstName',
                            id:'firstName',
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            label: 'Last Name',
                            placeHolder: 'Your Last Name',
                            name:'lastName'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'emailfield',
                            label: 'Email',
                            placeHolder: 'email@example.com'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            height: 37,
                            style: 'margin-left:35%',
                            width: 100,
                            iconAlign: 'center',
                            text: 'Submit',
                            action:'ContactSubmit'                        
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'hiddenfield',
                            id: 'HNumberOfBedRoom',
                            value:'2'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'hiddenfield',
                            id: 'HPetFriendlyId',
                            value:'2'
                        }                
                ]
}
```

In my controller, 
I have the following:

`refs: {
contactForm: '#contactForm'
}`

I can retrive the value by using

`var frmItems=this.getContactForm().getItems();

    console.log(frmItems.items[1]._value);`

This works fine but i want to retrieve the values something like

`frm.get('name/id of component')`

is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to assign an `id` to your field, and then `Ext.getCmp('-yourId-');` or `Ext.get('-yourId-');`

( http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-id )

Answer (score 8):

Use a Ext.form.Panel as your primary container.

example snippet

```
Ext.define('App.view.ContactForm',
{
  extend : 'Ext.form.Panel',
  xtype : 'contactform',
  id : 'contactForm',
  config : {
    items : [
      { 
        xtype : 'fieldset',
        items : [
           {
             {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                label: 'First Name',
                placeHolder: 'Your First Name',
                name:'firstName',
             },
         ]
       }
});
```

in your controller

refs : { contactForm : '#contactForm' }

then in your function you can either do

```
this.getContactForm().getValues().firstName
```

(uses the name value of the field)

or

```
var vals = this.getContactForm().getValues();
vals.firstName;
```

Avoid using Ext.getCmp() or a flat Ext.get() at the top level if you absolutely can help it.  If you're building custom controls you might have to make use of those, otherwise you're making things too hard on yourself.

Comment: This is way simpler, more organized, and expandable. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Dont struggle too much

first assign the id to that field and get the value using id thats it..

```
     {
          xtype: 'textfield',
          id: 'username',      // id
          name: 'username',
          placeHolder: '------UserName------',                 
        },


         Ext.getCmp('username').getValue();     // now get value using that id..
```

Answer (score 0):

```
refs:[
        {
            ref:'contentForm',
            // selector:'#contentForm'
            contentForm:'#contentForm'
        }
    ],
```

-

```
var form = Ext.getCmp('contentForm');

console.log(form.getValues());
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign `itemId: firstName` to `textfield`

And in `Controller`, where you want to get the value, use this:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('textfield[itemId=firstName]')[0].getData();
```